# How to copy data from an excel sheet to another excel sheet uploaded in sharepoint using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

i would like to ask if it's possible to copy or transfer data from an excel sheet to a worksheet uploaded in SharePoint without the need of opening the file from the SharePoint. Could this be done with VBA? You're prompt response is much appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Sharepoint you can use this code:
[Excel VBA Up-/Download from multiple SharePoint folders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30927462/4572953)

in order to open the SharePoint folders as network drive and access the files using `filesystemobject` or `dir` like you would do it on your local hard disk.

I currently recommend this method if you've enough drive letters available. 1 Letter is 1 folder. You can also connect to a root folder on SharePoint and browse to subfolders like you do it in explorer.

I hope it will help you. If you have any question, just ask.