# Excel VBA Up-/Download from multiple SharePoint folders

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I found sample code on the Internet for downloading files from a SharePoint folder using VBA (open in Explorer, map to drive letter, etc.)

Therefore, I wrote the following code:

```
Dim sharepointFolder As String
Dim colDisks As Variant
Dim objWMIService As Object
Dim objDisk As Variant
Dim driveLetter As String

'Create FSO and network object
Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Get all used Drive-Letters
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & "." & "\root\cimv2")
Set colDisks = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk")

'Loop through used Drive-Letters
For Each objDisk In colDisks
    For i = 65 To 90
        'If letter is in use exit loop and remember letter.
        If i = Asc(objDisk.DeviceID) Then
            j = i
            Exit For
        'letters which are not checked yet are possible only
        ElseIf i > j Then
            driveLetter = Chr(i) & ":"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    'If a Drive-Letter is found exit the loop
    If driveLetter <> "" Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next

'define path to SharePoint
sharepointFolder = "https://spFolder/Sector Reports/"
'Map the sharePoint folder to the free Drive-Letter
objNet.MapNetworkDrive driveLetter, sharepointFolder
'set the folder to the mapped SharePoint-Path
Set folder = fs.GetFolder(driveLetter)
```

At this stage I'm able to upload files to the folder:

```
https://spFolder/Sector Reports/
```

However, I also want to upload files to the folder e.g.:

```
https://spFolder/Documents/
```

and I also removed the previous drive letter using the function:

```
removeDriveLetter "Letter"
```

Now I have the problem, that if I map a new folder to a letter:

```
mapDriveLetter "A:\", sharepointFolder
```

and want to save something on this letter, it will always be saved on the previous path. For example:

```
mapDriveLetter "A:\", sharePointFolder1
removeDriveLetter "A:\"
mapDriveLetter "A:\", sharePointFolder2
workbook.saveas "A:\" & workbookName
```

In this case the workbook is always saved to the path given in "sharePointFolder1" and not this in "sharePointFolder2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved this issue as followed:

In case of connecting every folder, which contains the requested files, to a network drive letter, I put all folders into the same library and connected the root folder of the library to a network drive letter only.

In case of connection 
`https://spFolder/Sector Reports/` respectively `https://spFolder/Documents/`
I will connect `https://spFolder/` only and browse through the subdirectory using the File System Object.